# ASP.NET Identity - Multiple object sets per type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

> I got an error using ASP.NET Identity in my app. Multiple object sets
>   per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationRoles' and
>   'Roles' can both contain instances of type
>   'XXX.Identity.ApplicationRole'.

I saw a few questions about this error in stackoverflow. All indicate on two DbSet object of the same type. But in my DbContext there aren't the same types of DbSets.

Exception in thrown when i want enable automatic migration

My Contexts look like that:

```
public class XXXDbContext :
        IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
    public override IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserLogin> ApplicationUserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserClaim> AppApplicationUserClaims { get; set; 
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationAction> ApplicationActions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationActionRole> ApplicationActionRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do you have two entities bound to the same table? e.g. ApplicationUserRole and ApplicationRole

Comment: are you trying to override the default tables used in the IdentityDBContext?

Comment: yes i want to override them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your IdentityDbContext, the ApplicationRoles already define there may be it looks like that:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ApplicationRoles> Roles{ get; set; }
```

Remove that one, this error come while ApplicationRoles declares again in XXXcontext....

Answer (score 1):

Rather than overriding them, you can point the Identity classes to your own tables in your database and extend the functionality as required, as follows

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // Map Entities to their tables.
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().ToTable("Users");

    // Set AutoIncrement-Properties
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    // Override some column mappings that do not match our default
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.UserName).HasColumnName("username");
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("password");
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("lgn_key");
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.Email).HasColumnName("primaryEmail");
}
```